Windows 10 setup USBs appear bootable, but fail to load anything
So I got home yesterday to a wonderful bluescreen informing me that winboot.exe was corrupted on my home computer. The bootable device in there is pretty old, and these kinds of things happen every now and again to old SSDs, which is why I keep a Windows 10 setup USB in a nearby cabinet.
However, when I went to use the repair utility that comes with the setup USB I found that I was unable to load it. Booting to the UEFI image hangs forever (or, at least for many hours) on a black loading screen with the windows-style spinning-dots (but no windows logo: that appears and then eventually goes away, only the dots remain). Booting to the BIOS image is similar (infinite hang) but without the dots. I tried multiple USB ports to the same effect: the drive is always recognized as bootable, but I can't do anything useful with it.
So my next thought was to make my own. I've got my laptop running linux so I just used the KDE disk burning utility to burn a Windows 10 setup iso to a spare USB drive. This drive is recognized as bootable and appears in the list of bootable devices, however attempting to boot to it immediately kicks me back to the bluescreen informing me that winboot.exe is corrupted. That was confusing, since presumably it shouldn't matter if I'm booting from the USB image.
Anyway, I've got a cheap SSD on the way as a stop-gap, and I should be able to read my data back off the SSD anywhere it's not corrupted, so I'm not too worried about that. However I'd like to avoid buying a new copy of Windows and the hassle of setting everything back up.
To that end, if anyone has any thoughts as to why I can't boot to either recovery USB I'd be thrilled to hear them. I've got a lot more experience troubleshooting issues on Linux than Windows, so I'm close to the end of my own abilities in this case. Thanks to anyone who can help (and if nobody can, I suppose I'll just have to eat the cost of a new Windows license).

In Linux currently you can't make Windows installation media with the usual tools. Try Ventoy or MKUSB.

@ChanganAuto ahh that's interesting... it'd explain why it immediately kicked me back to the bluescreen when I tried to boot from that USB. I'll try re-burning that iso with Ventoy and share an update when I get home and can test it.

With Ventoy just install it then simply copy the ISOs.

Best success in making a bootable Win 10 repair USB, I've found, is with the Media Creation Tool, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 . Of course it only works from a Win 10 PC (or perhaps using a Win10 image in a VM??).

@DrMoishePippik Ventoy uses the ISOs "as is", decompressing and booting them on-the-fly. The result is always indistinguishable from any method that produces a bit-by-bit media copy, i.e., pretty much anything else except Rufus' default mode (dd mode can't be used with the current Windows ISOs anyway).

@ChanganAuto Ventoy did not work, but it appears as if nothing was going to. I've posted an answer with more details.

So after much mucking about, here's what I discovered:
There was probably nothing wrong with any of the USB installation media I had, be they original Windows 10 setup stick, Ventoy, or (what I ultimately ended up doing) a stick with the newest Windows 10 iso made using the official Microsoft tool.
The only thing that ended up fixing anything was putting a new SSD into the machine. New SSD boots right into the familiar Windows setup/repair dialog, and Windows installs with no issue. If the old SSD is in the machine it will not boot to any Windows iso, including the exact one I verified working with the new SSD.
So, something is definitely wrong with the SSD, and the Windows live media must be trying to access that disk or something and hanging when it fails.
As expected, I am able to mount and retrieve data from the old drive using my Linux machine (Linux continuing to be extremely reliable in situations like this). A few files beyond winboot.exe seem to have been corrupted, but nothing important.
